# Error in AJAX function, but not shown in traceback

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, django

The following is my Django view code snippet:

```
if (calltype == 'save'):
        response_data = {}
        bill_data = json.loads(request.POST.get('bill_details'))
        itemcode1=bill_data[0]['itemCode'] 
        #this part is just for checking
        response_data["name"] = itemcode1
        jsondata = json.dumps(response_data)
        return HttpResponse(jsondata)
```

The corresponding AJAX call & the code snippet to create the JSON objects are:

```
(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "", 
            type: "POST",
            data:{ bill_details: JSON.stringify(items),
                calltype: 'save',
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token},
            dataType: "application/json",               
            // handle a successful response
            success : function(jsondata) {  

                console.log(jsondata); // log the returned json to the console
                alert(jsondata['name']);
            },

                    // handle a non-successful response
                error : function() {
                    console.log("Error"); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
                }
        });
    }());
```

**Code snippet for creating JSON object**

```
( ".save" ).on("click", function(){
  alert("Clicked");

var items = [];

$("tr.data").each(function() {

    var code = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1) span').html();
    var quantity = $(this).find('td:nth-child(5) span').html();        

    var item = {
        itemCode : code,
        itemQuantity : quantity        
    };
    items.push(item);        
});
```

Now as I run this, there's no isse, but the AJAX call is always responding with error, although there's no error in traceback. Moreover, if I remove the error function, then neither is the success function called, nor is any eroor shown - either in console or traceback.

Might I request you why is this so?
Thank you for the response.

Comment: Where do `items` and `csrf_token` come from in your AJAX function?

Comment: items is created in the jquery script and I've the code snippet (the one for creating the JSON object) in the question. the csrf_token is declared in the html template.

Comment: Hey its working if I change dataype from 'application/json' to only 'json'. Might I know why??